# Running SonarQube in GitLab for android apps while using docker to build and test, when the sonar check runs it gives a Gradle error

Tags: android, docker, gradle, sonarqube, gitlab-ci

I have created the .gitlab-ci.yml for GitLab ci and the stages for build and test runs perfectly. And for this i have used a docker image too. when i try to add sonar to the pipeline im getting the following error.

```
    Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-bin.zip
...........10%............20%............30%............40%............50%............60%...........70%............80%............90%............100%
Welcome to Gradle 8.0.1!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Improvements to the Kotlin DSL
 - Fine-grained parallelism from the first build with configuration cache
 - Configurable Gradle user home cache cleanup
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/release-notes.html
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Configuration cache is an incubating feature.
Calculating task graph as no configuration cache is available for tasks: sonar
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'RDI'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.1
         project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:8.0.1
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
   > Could not resolve com.quittle:setup-android-sdk:3.1.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.quittle.setup-android-sdk:com.quittle.setup-android-sdk.gradle.plugin:3.1.0
      > No matching variant of com.quittle:setup-android-sdk:3.1.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.quittle:setup-android-sdk:3.1.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.quittle:setup-android-sdk:3.1.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.quittle:setup-android-sdk:3.1.0 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.quittle:setup-android-sdk:3.1.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
   > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.google.gms.google-services:com.google.gms.google-services.gradle.plugin:4.4.0
      > No matching variant of com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0.1' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 41s
Configuration cache entry stored.
```

Docker File

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Global Android command-line tools from https://developer.android.com/studio
ARG ANDROID_CMDLINE_TOOLS_VERSION=9477386
ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT "/sdk"
ENV ANDROID_HOME "/sdk"
ARG ANDROID_CMDLINE_TOOLS_BIN="${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/cmdline-tools/tools/bin"

# Add Gradle and SDK tools to the PATH
ENV PATH "$PATH:${ANDROID_CMDLINE_TOOLS_BIN}/:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools/:${ANDROID_HOME}/build-tools/30.0.3/"

# Setup distribution and install required distribution packages
ARG JDK_VERSION=17
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN dpkg --print-architecture && \
    dpkg --print-foreign-architectures

RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 && \
    dpkg --print-foreign-architectures

RUN apt-get -qq update && \
    apt-get install -qqy --no-install-recommends \
      curl \
      git-core \
      openjdk-8-jdk \
      openjdk-11-jdk \
      openjdk-17-jdk \
      libc6-i386 \
      libstdc++6:i386 \
      zlib1g:i386 \
      unzip \
      make \
      locales \
      autoconf \
      automake \
      libtool \
      pkg-config \
      wget \
      gcc \
      libsonic-dev \
      libpcaudio-dev \
      zip

RUN localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

RUN rm -f /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts; \
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure

# Download and install SDK command-line tools
RUN mkdir -p ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/cmdline-tools && \
    wget -q https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-${ANDROID_CMDLINE_TOOLS_VERSION}_latest.zip && \
    unzip *tools*linux*.zip -d ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/cmdline-tools && \
    mv ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/cmdline-tools/cmdline-tools ${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/cmdline-tools/tools && \
    rm *tools*linux*.zip

RUN yes | ${ANDROID_CMDLINE_TOOLS_BIN}/sdkmanager --licenses

RUN mkdir -p /root/.android \
 && touch /root/.android/repositories.cfg \
 && sdkmanager --verbose --update

ADD packages.txt /sdk
RUN sdkmanager --verbose --package_file=/sdk/packages.txt

RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y ruby && \
  apt-get install -y ruby-dev && \
  apt-get install -y build-essential

COPY Gemfile.lock .
COPY Gemfile .
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install
```

following script is what i am using to run sonar check in the yml file

```
sonarqube:
  stage: test
  image: gradle:jre11-slim
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"
    GIT_DEPTH: "0"
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  script:
    - ./gradlew sonar --stacktrace
  allow_failure: true
```

in the gradle file i have set the sonar properties

```
sonar {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", "<project-key>"
        property "sonar.qualitygate.wait", true
        property "sonar.host.url", "${SONAR_HOST_URL}"
        property "sonar.token", "${SONAR_TOKEN}"
        property "sonar.test.inclusions", "**/*Test*/**"
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
        property "sonar.gradle.skipCompile", true
        property "sonar.exclusions", '**/*Test*/**,' +
                '*.json,' +
                '**/*test*/**,' +
                '**/.gradle/**,' +
                '**/R.class'
    }
}
```

**SONAR_HOST_URL** and **SONAR_TOKEN** are set in the gitlab variables.

any suggestions to overcome this issue?